# Laravel using package [Requests for PHP]

Tags: php, laravel, path, python-requests, package

I am using Laravel 6.5.2 and trying to use the package "Requests for PHP". https://requests.ryanmccue.info/download/
I installed this package using composer. The reason I want to use this packages is that I have all CRUD scripts created (using above package) and would like to reuse the scripts.

I suspect there might be some name conflict since Laravel comes installed with a HTTP request solution called Request, meanwhile the [PHP Request] has the same name.

**Question:**
Has anyone succesfully installed [Requests for PHP] package and got it to work with Laravel 6.X ?

**Other findings:**
Whe comment-out the autoloader line, the corresponding page prints "hello" as it should. Leaving this line active indicates in the laravel stack trace that the error is the line that holds the autoloader.

**[Error]**

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Requests' not found

**[routes/web.php]**

```
Route::get("/requests", "Requests@read");
```

**[app/Http/Controllers]**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
// use Illuminate\Http\Request; // Standard line, creeating a controller.

require_once '../vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php';
Requests::register_autoloader();


class Requests extends Controller {
    public function read() {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Name won't collide because of different namespaces. Btw, `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Requests'` is a directory.

Comment: @TheAlpha Thanks, I did not find a way forward, so I am testing Guzzle in parallel, until I might get some tip for the [Requests for PHP].

Comment: as previously said, the `Request` from Laravel is in its own namespace and named `Request` not `Requests` so there won't be a conflict ... your application itself may have an alias for `Request` in the root namespace but it isn't `Requests` ... and just let composer handle the loading if possible